# Tool to find and remove duplicates in the Favourites folder?

Tags: windows-7

My Favourites in IE 8 seems to have lots of duplicate links: is there a simple tool available which allows me to run My Favourites folder through it to find duplicates?  It would be nice if the tool showed a list of possible duplicates before deleting any links.

Win 7 64-bit.
IE 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FavoritesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/faview.html) or [AM-DeadLink](http://aignes.com/deadlink.htm) tools

Comment: Thanks. Both products say this line: "tab delimited text files." <--- what does it mean?